# How to manually manage text wrapping in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

When working with designers, they often are very picky about word wrap in the completed HTML page. Assuming that I'm working on a fixed layout (not-responsive), and the designer does not like the way text is wrapping, I can:

- Adjust `padding-right`
- Add manual `<br>` to break a line
- Add manual `&nbsp;` to avoid a break (typically for orphan control)

(In my case, I'm designing for a specific mobile device, so I know the screen size, and can control the fonts. Also, making the designers happy is non-negotiable.)

The issue that I keep running into is that the text or layout will be updated later, and relics of this specific word wrap concern, which no longer apply, introduce issues we then need to fix.

So I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a strategy that:

1. Allows completely arbitrary control of word wrap in individual
   cases; but,
2. Doesn't make everything so hard to maintain going forward

I'm open to procedural, algorithmic (javascript), or CSS-oriented suggestions.

Comment: Don't forget the wonderful soft hyphen `&shy;` for controlling how individual words might split.

Comment: Have you tried white-space? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: And the `<wbr>` element represents a line break opportunity, but does not force a line break.  Basically it tells the browser "if you think you need a line break somewhere, this is a good spot".

Comment: white-space would let me turn off wrapping all together, like with a <pre> element. But The crux of the problem is that 95% of the text wraps just fine automatically. The designers focus on a small subset of text that rubs them the wrong way, and we need to fix a bunch of little cases. Then those fixes hang around long after the text and layout have changed, causing a whole new class of problems.

Comment: How about text-align justify? Would the designers be happy then? How about the `<pre>' tag? Is that workable? Now, I understand this is non-negotiable but if the designers find it THAT IMPORTANT for a line break to occur here or there - then make it a new paragraph. That will always be on its own line.

Comment: I have never, in my entire life, met a designer who likes justified text. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the strategy I chose. Time will tell how maintainable it is.

1. Do not edit the text content
2. Fix wrapping by adding CSS classes that change the way the text flows, but do not use attributes like width or padding that are already being used to control layout

Specifically:

```
.tighten {
    letter-spacing: -0.011em;
}
.loosen {
    letter-spacing: 0.011em;
}
.hyphenate {
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: 4;
    -webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: 4;
}
```

It turns out that these imperceptible changes in spacing can make a huge difference in wrap. I actually have several variations of these classes, so I can try progressively more or less space to fix wrapping.

In severe cases, I use the hyphenate class (I'm only targeting iOS in this case).

In a future revision, when we change the text in a div, we can just remove the tighten, loosen, or hyphenate class from that div, and see if there are any wrap issues we need to correct. If there are, we go through the original trial-and-error of seeing which class gives the best look.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` tag so you can insert preformated text.